# How can one create a method in scala that generates the sqlcontext implicits encoder based only on type?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to build a framework on top of spark that can automatically create datasets from data store to disk. An example of the sort of thing I would like to do is:

```
var sparkSession: SparkSession = _ // initialized elsewhere

def generateDataset[T <: Product : TypeTag](path: Path): Dataset[T] = {
  val df: DataFrame = generateDataFrameFromPath(path)
  import sparkSession.implicits._
  df.as[T]
}
```

which works just fine. The problem I have is trying to extend that to `Dataframe`s and other classes for which implicit encoders can be generated (like `String` or `Int`). I have tried to do something like this:

```
var sparkSession: SparkSession = _ // initialized elsewhere

def generateDataset[T : TypeTag](path: Path): Dataset[T] = {
  val df: DataFrame = generateDataFrameFromPath(path)
  typeOf[T] match {
    case t if t =:= typeOf[Row] => df
    case t if t <:< typeOf[Product] =>
      import sparkSession.implicits._
      df.as[T]
  }
}
```

But the compiler doesn't like this even though we know `T` is a subclass of `Product` when we call `.as[T]`.

I know that the standard approach would be to use the `Encoder` context bound/implicit however my calling code has no knowledge of the `sparkSession` until it gets the data back.

Is there a way to get this to work without having the encoder generated by the caller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try generating encode in place:

```
def generateDataset[T : TypeTag](path: Path) = {
  val df: DataFrame = generateDataFrameFromPath(path)
    typeOf[T] match {
      case t if t =:= typeOf[Row] => df
      case t if t <:< typeOf[Product] =>
        implicit val enc: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[T] =  
          org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder()
        df.as[T]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a nice solution to the specific issue. Would have been nice if there was a way to do it with the implicit encoders but this works for me :)